# "path must exist" for Cucumber + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I made a `Spring Boot 2` application with one endpoint to execute `Cucumber test` for 5.7.0 version

```
@PostMapping("/integration")
public Object runCucumber(@RequestBody List<String> request) {
    try {

        String pathDirectory = "src/main/resources/" + request.get(0);


        String response = String.valueOf(Main.run(new String[]{"--glue", //Cucumber type (--glue)
                        "pmc/aop/integration", // the package which contains the glue classes
                        pathDirectory} //Step package
                , Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(request);

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {

        log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());

        return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatusCode()).body(ex.getStatusText());

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(ex.getLocalizedMessage());

    }
}
```

The request used

```
[
"features/local/notify.feature"
]
```

[image]

As you can see I'd like to execute the `notify.feature` inside of `local` folder, inside of `features` folder, inside of `resources` folder

this is the configuration

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@CucumberOptions(features="src/main/resources")
public class CucumberConfiguration {
}
```

Everything is going good, locally but on my server I got

`path must exist: /app/src/main/resources/features/local/heal.feature`

What's wrong?

Comment: Aren't those directories supposed to be named like `features.local` instead of `f.local` etc?

Comment: @MinarMahmud I know the extension file is ``.feature``. I guess the directory name doesn't matter

Comment: `path must exist: /app/src/main/resources/features/local/heal.feature`.  it is searching in a path where directory name is `feature` but not `f`. You might consider changing that and see what happens

Comment: @MinarMahmud sorry for misunderstand. My IDE has flatten packages. I change the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application is deployed the `src/main/resources/` directory does not exist. You can verify this by inspecting the contents of the jar or war file you've created.

Instead, try locating the feature on the class path. E.g. `classpath:com/example/app/my.feature`.

Comment: I would expect that to happen.

Comment: you suggest to move the resource content inside ``pmc.aop.integration`` where is the classpath but its gong to mess up the project structure

Comment: Inspect the contents of the jar file.

Comment: another way to change the classpath?

Comment: Please look at the contents of the jar file. Resources in `src/main/resources` are on the classpath.

Comment: My extraction programms (the unarchive and Bettezip) can't extract the content from app.jar

Comment: The file format is zip, rename the file to `.zip` or use your java utils. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

Comment: I couldn't extract ``app.jar`` but I could extract ``app.jar.original`` however I can see in the same level ``application.yml`` file, ``features`` folder and ``pmc``

Comment: The problems is consume the feature using classpath. Other user told we need to comsume it as a ``Imputstream`` however Main.Run does not recieve ``imputstream``